# How to migrate SpringBootApp to library via spring.factories?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

We've built a Spring service discovery solution that autowires several local classes annotated with `@Component` or `@Service` through a component scan at the root package level via `@SpringBootApplication`.  The project follows a  standard maven/spring layout:

```
project
  src/main/java
    service
      - ServiceA.java
      - ServiceB.java
      ...
    model
      - modelA.java
      ...
    component
      - ComponentA.java
      - ComponentB.java

    BootApp.java
    pom.xml
```

We'd like to now distribute this internally as a library, and doing so requires a `spring.factories` file (see [how marathon does it](https://github.com/aatarasoff/spring-cloud-marathon/blob/master/starter/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories) / see [spring autoconfig docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)).  Looking at other service-discovery implementations like `marathon` and `eureka`, it appears that I should remove all autowiring annotations (ie. `@Component` and `@Service`) and instead manually configure all of the components/beans into one or more `@Configuration` classes.  The app is already autowiring and bootstrapping over ten classes- I'd prefer to not have to refactor and manually wire these up.

**My question**: is there any way to simply retain the existing autowiring/project structure and have `spring.factories` pick it up in something similar to a component scan?  Something like:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=project.BootApp
```

or

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=project.*
```

Are there any other tips or best practices on how refactor to support `spring.factories` without having a massive `@Configuration` class?  Is it possible to split the difference and have most of our internal objects autowired but then manually configure public objects like `DiscoveryClient` and `ServiceRegistery` (see [spring cloud SPI](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-commons)) and reference them in `spring.factories`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it is possible to use `@ComponentScan` in a very similar way to `@SpringBootApplication`

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.bnymellon.tsg.discovery.springcloud.autoconfig")
public class BootApp {

}
```

The key difference is that `@SpringBotApplication` contains `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, which doesn't play nice here.

PS - I was not inheriting from `spring-starter-parent` so `spring.factories` was not included in the built artifact.  Had to add the following to `pom.xml`

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.factories</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

I guess at the end of the day, autowiring through annotations (eg. `@Service`) is a valid approach and I was incorrect in the question to presume it was incompatible with spring.factories.